# How to disable HTML characters escaping in whisker.render in R

Tags: r, parsing, templates, special-characters

Package `whisker`

```
whisker.render("& Hello {{place}}", list("place" = "&World"))
```

And the output is:

```
[1] "& Hello &amp;World"
```

The question is: how to disable escaping HTML codes? So that the code above would produce:

```
[1] "& Hello &World"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use triple mustaches to prevent escaping.

```
whisker.render("& Hello {{{ place }}}", list("place" = "&World"))
```

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation of whisker:

```
template <-
’Hello {{name}}
You have just won ${{value}}!
```

So I Tried this:

```
whisker.render("& Hello &{{place}}", list("place" = "World!"))
```

And got the output as:

```
[1] "& Hello &World!"
```

**New Approach:**

I tried this:

```
y <-whisker.render("& Hello {{place}}", list("place" = "&World"))
```

Output for this is :>

```
y
[1] "& Hello &amp;World"
```

Then I used gsub function on y like this:

```
> gsub("&amp;", "&", y)
[1] "& Hello &World"
```

which gave the above output.

Instead of storing the value in a separate string, I applied gsub for the whisker function:

```
gsub("&amp;", "&", whisker.render("& Hello {{place}}", list("place" = "&World")))
```

Only pitfall with this approach is that we must be aware about the string escaping sequences.

Comment: It's possible, but what if "&" symbol is in the "place" variable? Then it's escaped. The function treats template and replacements differently.

Comment: I have figured that, tried gsub function also, but it was futile. Also tried as.charachter too, again, no positive result.

Comment: Thank you a lot. How can I make the last step `gsub("&amp;", "&", y)` over all HTML special characters? Maybe some R package for HTML?

Comment: @Anton: if else with different escape sequence might work. I have created a vector, escapeseq <- c("$amp;", "$gt;", "&lt;"), then individual access and then using gsub may help. I will be working on this though.

Comment: @Anton: I have found this: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/dsl.html, he has created a function to escape charachter HTML, need to reverse in our case.